# Tramp using su fails with powerline prompt

Tags: tramp

I'm having a weird problem opening files as root. From emacs -Q, I issue `(require 'tramp)`, customize tramp-verbose to 10, and try to open a file as root: `C-x C-f /su::/etc/fstab`. I'm then prompted for my root password. Entering the password, Emacs pauses for ca. 10 seconds, then appears to open a new file called fstab, but it's not the fstab that already exists in /etc/fstab. The message about calling make-directory to create the parent directories shows up, so I've apparently opened a new file somewhere. I can't see where, exactly, as `C-x C-f`, or even `M-x shell-commmand pwd` both prompt me for the root password, and then fail.

Despite having turned `tramp-verbose` to the maximum value, there's not much in my ***Messages*** buffer after all this:

> Creating customization setup...done
>   Tramp: Opening connection for root@onottra672626p using su...
>   Tramp: Sending command ‘exec su - root’
>   Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
>   Tramp: Sending Password
>   Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
>   Tramp: Opening connection for root@onottra672626p using su...failed
>   Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents
>
> Tramp: Checking ‘vc-registered’ for /su:root@onottra672626p:  /etc/fstab...failed
>   Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents
>   Tramp: Opening connection for root@ using su...
>   Tramp: Sending command ‘exec su - root’
>   Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...
>   Tramp: Sending Password
>   Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed
>   Tramp: Opening connection for root@onottra672626p using su...failed
>   Quit

This is all on a laptop, I'm not trying to connect to another machine.

Emacs 25.1.91.1, and confirmed again with Emacs 25.2.1.

Any suggestions for further troubleshooting, or is this just a regular bug?

## Update

The problem was due to my use of the [powerline prompt](https://github.com/banga/powerline-shell). The debug-log contained the lines:

```
08:34:24.189824 tramp-accept-process-output (10) # *tramp/su root@....* run *tramp/su root@....*

[30;41m~ [0;31m [m
```

The `` symbol is provided by powerline. Tramp needs to detect shell prompts, and this unexpected character was confusing it. The fix required modifying the variable `tramp-shell-prompt-pattern` to include the new symbol:

Original value was: 
"\(?:^\|
\)[^]#$%>\n]*#?[]#$%>] *\(\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z] *\)*"

New new, corrected value is
"\(?:^\|
\)[^]#$%>\n]*#?[]#$%>``] *\(\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z] *\)*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the records, this has been discussed on the [Emacs bugtracker](https://debbugs.gnu.org/25963). It's not a Tramp error, but an unusual prompt from the remote machine.